# Geometry calculations of a crop\zoom tool in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, math, geometry, crop

I'm writing a new crop\zoom tool in jQuery and I've hit a wall with simple geometry. Please take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/74Jep/33/

The way it works is this: the image to be cropped\zoomed rests inside a "dragcontainer" (yellow background), that sits inside a viewport (black border rectangle). The viewport will have "overflow: hidden", and so will reveal only a portion of the image.

The user has two controls - one for dragging the image to position it inside the viewport, and the other to zoom out from the original image.

It works okay, but I'm having problems adjusting the image position while zooming, so that the zoom in\zoom out looks correct.

**What I want:**
When zoomed, the image should change scale using the center of the viewport as a registration point, and not "slip" to the sides.

**More info:**

This happens due to the fact the the scaling done by the browser uses the top left of the image as a registration point. The yellow dragcontainer is scaled properly, but The fact that its size doesn't change linearly really confused me when trying to solve this. I was forced to rely on a really ugly hack to check if the image left the dragcontainer, and if so return it to its proper spot, rather than calculate it properly.

I would love it if someone could chip in his two cents, and elaborate on what should the proper way to calculate the top\left position of the image inside the dragcontainer while zooming so it would "look right".

Answer (score 0):

You could find the difference in width of the image before and after each zoom, and then move the image half of the difference to the left or right, depending on zooming in or out.

The same could be done for the height and top/bottom.

Hope this helps - there may be an easier way this was my first thought. If anything else jumps to mind ill come back

Comment: That helped somewhat, thanks! 
I ended doing a combination of your suggestions + doing an offset brute force checking of whether the image has left the bounds of the drag container, and if so push it back inside. Not the most elegant solutions -  but it works

Answer (score 0):

May be this plugin will help you, it seems to do what you're looking for: http://www.tmatthew.net/jwindowcrop